# search in multidimensional array php

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array with various sites links, here is output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.msn.com/etc
            [1] => http://www.yahoo.com/etc
            [2] => http://www.google.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.abc.com/etc
            [1] => http://www.hotmail.com/etc
            [2] => http://www.hotmail.com/page/2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.live.com/etc
            [1] => http://www.google.com/etc
            [2] => http://www.stock.com
        )

)
```

I wants to match multiple URL's, here my example code:

```
$sites = array("msn.com","hotmail.com","live.com");
$links = array(
    array("http://www.msn.com/1","http://www.yahoo.com/etc","http://www.google.com"),
    array("http://www.msn.com/2","http://www.hotmail.com/","http://www.hotmail.com/page/2"),
    array("http://www.live.com/etc","http://www.google.com/etc","http://www.stock.com")
);
```

I need whatever sites are in $sites,first it will find msn.com site from $links array, so if it found msn.com in first array($links[0]) it will not search msn.com in other $links array but keep searching for other (hotmail.com and live.com), and if it find 2 links of same host in one array, it will join them, means if it finds a host in one array element it will not search that host in other elements of $links array, so final output from above will be this:

```
Array
(
    [msn] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.msn.com/1
        )

    [hotmail] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.hotmail.com/
            [1] => http://www.hotmail.com/page/2
        )

    [live] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.live.com/etc
        )

)
```

I am not sure how to perform this task, I would be grateful for any input. Thanks

Comment: foreach($sites as $site){
// just this i dont know what to do next sorry
}

Comment: It's possible to do this with programming, but I doubt anybody will write the code for you because the algorithm you look for is akward and not helpful for any future visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

best I'll give you is pseudo code.

```
for each of the links arrays
    for each of the non eliminated sites
        find all the matching entries in this link array, for this site
        if theres at least one match
            eliminate this site from the list
            store the matches into a results array indexed by sitename, 
            --for example $results[$sitename] = $matchesArray
```

have fun

Answer (score -1):

Here is the complete code:

```
$final = array();
foreach($sites as $site)
{
    $found = false;
    foreach($links as $link_batch)
    {   
        foreach($link_batch as $link)
        {
            if(strpos($link, $site))
            {
                $found = true;
                $final[$site][] = $link;
            }
        }
        if($found)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
print_r($final);
```